# GitLab, Cloning 2 exisitng projects to a single root folder

Tags: gitlab, clone, git-clone

I started by creating my own project on Gitlab first. Now I want to do the following:
There are two existing projects on GitLab, both have their own HTTPS Link that you need in order to clone the project. Now I want to create a folder and clone both projects inside of that folder. How can I clone two existing projects to a single root folder?

Comment: the question is what do you want to achieve? do you want to merge them together, should they coexist side by side? - i do not think it make sense to merge two different projects within one directory. So to give a good answer, more detail about the motivation would be highly appreciated

Comment: Hello Simon, thanks for comment, they should not be merged. As you mentioned they should coexist side by side within a folder and both have to be cloned within that folder. And the resulting folder is going to be the project as a whole I am working on. I hope this is more detailed.